# how to calculate efficent how many elements in a list are the same?

Tags: java

I need to do the following task:

- I have a list with items.
- Each of the items also have a List with strings like "`gkejgueieriug`"
- Now I need to run throw the list and check how many of the items in the list of each item are also in the current element

here is a small pseudeo code:

```
OneItem;
List AllItems;
for Item in AllItems:
    int count = number strings in Item.Values which are also in OneItem.Values
```

because the data is very big, I need some help to make a efficent implementation.

How to do this? Should I use a hashmap? how to count the overlap?

Comment: Don't pre-maturely optimise. Just write a clear solution and benchmark to see if this actually causes problems in your application.

Comment: Given that two answers are already referring to `Set`s, I will ask: is it possible for `Item.Values` to contain duplicate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide detailed information about the involved types which you want to compare. So I assume you have a `List<Item>`. Each item has a `String` and an own `List<Item>`

So first I would create a `HashSet` of the `String`s of the `Items` in your `AllItems`-List. Iterate the `AllList` and add the String of each `Item` to the `HashSet`.
Then in the second step iterate the `AllList` again and iterate the `List` in the `Item`s and check each String here if it is in the HashSet which was created before.

If you have to check this several times you can keep the HashSet as a cache which you refresh when the `AllList` gets changed.

```
// Step 1: Create Set of Strings
Set<String> allStrings = new HashSet<String>();
for (Item item : allList) {
   allStrings.add(item.getString());
}

// Step 2: Calculate occurrences
for (Item item : allList) {
   for (Item internalItem : item.getItems()) {
       if (allStrings.contains(internalItem.getString()) {
           // Count one up for this String
           // This might be done by replacing the HashSet by a HashMap and use its values for counting
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Item.Values a Set rather than a List. A decent Set implementation - like a HashSet - will run the contains() operation in constant time. Then iterate over one set and increment a count each time the other set contains the element.

An optimization is to always iterate over the smaller set. That way the counting operation is O(n) where n is the size of the smaller set.

Comment: This assumes `Item.Values` contains no duplicates, which may not be the case.

Comment: But this is okay there should be no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If the comparison is only one way (i.e. only counting strings in one list that are also in another but NOT the other way around) then the best way of doing it would probably be to put both lists in a Set instead:

```
HashSet firstSet = ...
HashSet secondSet = ...

for(each value in firstSet)
{
    if(secondSet.contains(value)
    {
        // Do what you want with the value.
        // Sugestion: Add value to a separate set
        // so you can track duplicates etc
    }
}
```

Comment: there is not only one secondSet, there is a list of many. And I just need the count of the elements which are the same.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you create an `ArrayList` of `Map` with the string values and the number of matches in your OneItem.Values...

```
ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>> matches=new ArrayList<>();
for (Item i : AllItems) {
      Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
      for(String s:values){
        map.put(s,Collections.frequency(OneItem.Values, s));
      }
      matches.add(map); 
}
```